# Extract part of a URL in specific format

Tags: ruby

I have twitter URLs that may take the following formats:

```
urls = [
  "https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "http://twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "https://www.twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "http://www.twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "www.twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744",
  "m.twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744",
]
```

I want to get the username `"TwitterDev"` from any of the above. How can I get the words/numbers/charectors [sic] after `".com/"` up to the next `"/"`?

Comment: more cleaner version with lookahead and look behind `(?<=\.com\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=\/)`

Comment: `(?<=twitter\.com\/)[^\/]+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the exact specification that you mentioned.

```
urls.map{|url| url.split(".com/", 2).last.split("/", 2).first}
# => ["TwitterDev", "TwitterDev", "TwitterDev", "TwitterDev", "TwitterDev", "TwitterDev", "TwitterDev"]
```

Comment: How would i write this onto something like this in my controller: @order_twitter_tag = @order.twitter_link.#regex_goes_here ? - i Tried "@order_twitter_tag = @order.twitter_link.map{|url| url.split(".com/", 2).last.split("/", 2).first}" but it gives me "no method map..." - but the string does exist so i'm not sure why it gives an error

Comment: @uno Your `@order.twitter_link` is something other than an array, most likely `nil`.

Comment: Yes, it's not an array, its just one string.  Does that change things? How should i set it up just for one url being entered?

Comment: NVM, I'm an idiot.  I think I got it - will do more more testing real quick - thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can not write ruby but this is what I get from the auto-generated code from regex101.com site with [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/h1iODS/3/) `(?<=\.com\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=\/)` using **look-behind** and **look-behind** approach. It just grabs the string part that has `.com/` before and `/` after it.

```
re = /(?<=\.com\/)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=\/)/m
str = '-https://twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744 

 -http://twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744 

 -twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744 

 -https://www.twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744 

 -http://www.twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744 

 -www.twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744 

 -m.twitter.com/TwitterDev/status/850006245121695744 '

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

**EDITED:**  Cleanest and Fastest way using `(?<=twitter\.com\/)[^\/]+`

Comment: `[^\/]+` for the real match is faster and safer against e.g. tomorrow’s twitter decision to allow non-latin alphabet symbols for names.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin agreed sir and added on the **Edited** section

Comment: Do i need to create a method for this? And I tried your edited version and I getthis error: "syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'", "unknown regexp options - rdr", "unmatched close parenthesis: /]+)".... while using... " @order_twitter_tag = @order.twitter_link.sub((?<=twitter\.com\/)[^\/]+) "